# Turtle graphics not showing although code to do so is present

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

My code is below but although this should work as I am following my professors instruction and his as this was written works it doesn't on my machine. Is there something I missed for the turtle graphics window to not even show?

That is the problem. The turtle graphics window wont appear nothing is executed and I am confused.

Here is the out put in the shell

```
>>> drawKoch(1)
>>>
```

and the code below:

```
  def koch(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 'F'

    tmp = koch(n-1)

    return tmp + 'L' + tmp +'R' + tmp + 'L' + tmp

  from turtle import Screen, Turtle

  def drawKoch(n):

    s = Screen()
    t = Turtle()
    directions = koch(1)

    for move in directions:
        if move == 'F':
            t.forward (300/3**n)
        if move == 'L':
            t.lt(60)
        if move == 'R':
            t.rt(120)
    s.bye()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the `s.bye()` in the last line.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.bye), calling `bye` would close the window.

So what you are telling Python to do is:

1. Open the window
2. Move the turtle around
3. Shut down the window

As these steps run very fast, you can't even tell if they are running at all.

To fix this problem, you may replace `bye` with `exitonclick`.

Comment: yes but doesnt the program have to first draw the program and then close the window? I have no window open. But I will try it with removing the s.bye() and post my result

Comment: removing s.bye() had no effect still the same problem

Comment: @ChristopherJakob Either removing `s.bye()` or replacing it with `exitonclick` works for me. I can see the movements.

Comment: yep that did it,  replacing bye with exitonclick worked. thank you

Answer (score -1):

As what @satoru said, my problem was that I was using s.bye() which would close the python window before I could see anything happening.

What I needed to use and am currently using is s.exitonclick()

giggles